# einen Pflock einschlagen

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could anyone explain me, how should I understand the expression "einen Pflock einschlagen"? Of course, I mean something more then just hammering the peg. Like in this sentence:

Österreichs neuer Kanzler Sebastian Kurz schlug in Brüssel schon gleich einen Pflock ein: "Die EU muss schlanker werden".

Comment: "Dropping an anchor" maybe.

Comment: I’d translate it almost literally as „he staked a claim“.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that „einen Pflock einschlagen“, which indeed means driving a stake in the ground, here simply means „leave a mark“, in the sense of  „staking a claim“ or „leaving an impression“.

Answer (score 3):

> Österreichs neuer Kanzler Sebastian Kurz schlug in Brüssel schon gleich einen Pflock ein: "Die EU muss schlanker werden".

That *Pflock* above is a stake, meant for marking the outline of a building on a construction site. Austria's new chancellor had driven his stake into the ground, marking his future EU as a smaller building than the old one.

Answer (score 2):

When you claim a piece of land, you need to hammer pegs into the ground to mark your territory. Later you can use those pegs to build a fence around your land.

When Sebastian Kurz hammered his peg into the ground, he set a mark. He was claiming something. He claims that the European Union must get slimmer.

Answer (score 1):

**DE**

»schlug einen Pflock ein« drückt aus, dass der Autor Kurz' Aussage als nachdrückliche, unverrückbare Forderung versteht. So, als hätte Kurz hinzugefügt: »Ohne das geht es nicht.«

**EN**

»schlug einen Pflock ein« expresses that the author takes Kurz' statement as insistent, unalterable demand. As if Kurz would have added: »Ohne das geht es nicht.« (»There's no way without it.«)